# Issues with Google Sheets API Authentication in Android

Tags: android, firebase, google-sheets, google-oauth, google-sheets-api

I'm attempting to interact with the [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts)
to [create and modify](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/create) spreadsheets in my Android application.

1. **Successful Google Account Authentication**:
   I have successfully followed the steps outlined in Authenticate with [Google on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin) and have managed to log in to my Google account using Firebase Authentication.
2. **Spreadsheets.create Method** I am attempting to use the Spreadsheets.create method to create a spreadsheet. I have specified the required credentials scopes

   ```
   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
   ```

   in the OAuth consent screen on the `Google Cloud -> API and services -> OAuth consent screen scopes`
3. **Authentication Token Handling:**
   After successful user authentication, I store the googleIdToken. I then attempt to use this token in the Spreadsheet create method using Retrofit.

   **Retrofit Builder Configuration** where I set the `authorization` header:

   ```
   Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .client(OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(chuckerInterceptor)
        .addInterceptor { chain ->
        val request = chain.request().newBuilder()
            .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer $googleIdToken")
            .build()
        chain.proceed(request)
    }.build())
    .build()
    .create(SpreadsheetApi::class.java)
   ```

   **SpreadsheetApi**

   ```
   import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.model.Spreadsheet

   interface SpreadsheetApi {
      @POST("spreadsheets")
      suspend fun createSpreadsheet(@Body() spreadsheet: Spreadsheet): Spreadsheet
   }
   ```
4. **Error Encountered:**
   However, I am facing an issue and receiving the following error:

   ```
   URL: https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets
   Method: POST
   ---------- Request ----------
   Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1Ni*****

   ---------- Response ----------
   {
      "error": {
         "code": 401,
         "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access 
          token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See 
          https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
          "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
      }
   }
   ```

Thanks!